# Show the correct input file name in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a simple add function in my table.
I would like to post the name of each uploaded file on the table, but it seems like it's only working on the first 2 rows due to my **var i = 0;** is not working properly.
Here is my code:

```
<table id='datarows'>
<tr>
<td>Upload</td><td>Filename</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="file" id="ProductImage" name="ProductImage0" onchange="getFileData(this);"/></td>
<td><input id="filename" name="filename0" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addProduct()">ADD NEW PRODUCT</a><br />

<script>

var i = 0;
function addProduct() {
var str =   '<tr><td><input type="file" id="ProductImage'+i+'" 
name="ProductImage'+i+'"  onchange="getFileData2(this);" /></td>'
str = str + '<td ><input id="filename'+i+'" name="filename'+i+'" type="text" 
/></td></tr>';
$('#datterrows').append(str);
}

//----- Upload picture/file and add name table 1
function getFileData(myFile) {
    var file = document.getElementById("ProductImage").value;
    var msg = document.getElementById("filename");
    msg.value = "test"+file; 
}

//----- Upload picture/file and add name table 2
function getFileData2(myFile) {
    var file = document.getElementById("ProductImage"+i).value;
    var msg = document.getElementById("filename"+i);
    msg.value = "test" + file;
}

</script>
```

I don't get any errors but all I see is the my input id keeps repeating it self to be productimage0 and not continuing for each element I add.
I hope someone can help, it's been pain in the a**

Comment: So why dont you have `i = i+1;` at the end of the `addProduct` function?

Comment: What difference would it make if it starts with 0 or 1? I have tested anyways and it didnt work :/

Comment: It should start indeed from `i=1` since you already have row 0 by default, but you have to keep increasing the counter at the end of the `addProduct` after you `append` so that you keep getting new values for `i`

Comment: I suppose people need some clarifications from you: where and what is `$('#datterrows')?` Why is there two functions `getFileData` with the first one unused? You are adding two `<td>` but not creating any `<tr>` tag... Where do you incremement i? There is no value attribute on ProductImage td... What should it be? This would be helpful, thx :)

Comment: I'm sorry, 'datarows' is the ID of the table.
The reason I added 2 getFileData, is because there are 2 tables in my example where the second one is the one in the str. I know it's supposed to be one table only. But how else would I be able to add rows to the table